# how to get parallelStream() current index

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm parsing html links using parallelStream() as suggested here: 
[Jsoup parsing - parsing multiple links simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324372/jsoup-parsing-parsing-multiple-links-simultaneously).

```
 public static void createPageListByObject(String urlsFileName, int Y) throws IOException {
      //List<String> URLs = new ArrayList<>();
      int indx = 1;

      URLs.parallelStream().forEach(URL-> {
        try {
            Page page = Page.Generate(URL, Y);
            FileUtils.writePageToFile(page, indx++);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + ". Skipping to next url");
        }
    });

  public static Page Generate(String URL, int Y) throws IOException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, URISyntaxException {
    Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Chrome/5.0").timeout(10 * 1000).execute();
    Page tutorialPage = new Page(URL);
    return tutorialPage;
}

 public static void writePageToFile(Page page, int i) throws IOException{
    String directoryName = getDirectory(page.vectorXY().Y);
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(directoryName + "//page" + i));

    os.writeObject(page);
    os.close();
}
```

The problem is that using the parallelStream() i sometimes get the same index twice and the file is overwritten. i somewhow need to get the current index parallelStream is working on.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java iterator implementation hides the current index. Actually iterator is used for iterating without an index.

If you really need index, create an list of  objects containing url and an index. This is just sample encapsulate it properly.

```
class UrlObject {
  private String url;
  private Integer index;
  public UrlObject(String url, Integer index){
    .....
  }
  // getter and setter
}
```

So when you add item to list add using

```
List<UrlObject> URLs = new ArrayList<>();
URLS.add(new URLObject("url here", <index here>));

URLs.parallelStream().forEach(url-> {
  // code here url.getUrl() and url.getIndex()
});
```

Or you can use any other method.